# issue dynamically checking password

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, forms

Here is my scenario, I present the user with a table of tests, which I have retrieved from my database in a loop and created a form for each test(row of table). So each has a submit button to execute that particular test.

basics of my loop:

```
while ($ts = mysql_fetch_assoc($test_info))
{
 //PRESENT VALUES $ts['name'] in table within a unique form etc.
}
```

What I am trying to do and failing is, on clicking a particular submit button for a test, to run a JS function which checks; if the test has a password attached, if it does, present a popup form for password input, and on submitting that small form check if password is correct, if it is submit the original test form.

My problem is that I cannot parse the password value attached to that form to my javascript.

so ideally i want to do this:

```
<input id='submit' type='button' onclick='JSfunction(test_password)' value='execute test' >
```

So I can somehow parse a value from that particular form to a javascript function without actually submitting the form.

and I believe I know how to do the rest in my JSfunction.

I hope somebody can follow my poor explanation and point me in the right direction.

Many thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When a form should have a password associated with it, add the following:

```
<input type="hidden" name="has_password" value="yes" />
<input type="hidden" name="password" value="" />
```

Then, in your check triggered by the submit button (assuming the button itself is the `this` context):

```
if ($(this).parent().find(':input:hidden[name=has_password]').val() == 'yes') {
    // pop password request
    return false;
}
```

You'll need a way to store the context of the current form, and I can suggest a few if you like, but you can then populate the password into the hidden field for it and submit as normal.  By the way, you might want to consider `onSubmit` instead of the submit button's `onClick`, as `onSubmit` will catch attempts by scripts to perform a submit.  If you do this, just remove the `.parent()` portion of the above, as the `<form>` element should be the `this` context.

Comment: can I access the values of the form in a similar way? so when I verify `has_password` is 'yes' I can then grab the actual password from my database with the test name from the form. If that makes sense :S

Comment: I'm not sure what you're talking about doing.  Do you mean you want to do the comparison on the client side?  That's not such a good idea.  I was assuming you'd pop up a generic shadowbox that asks for a password, and then populates the hidden password field, then calls the `submit()` method on the relevant form.  What is it exactly you want to do?